# Is the delay line and bounded operator in a normed space?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be the normed space of all bounded real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with norm defined by

$$
\|x\| = \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}}{|x(t)|}
$$

and let $T: X \rightarrow X$ be defined by

$$
y(t) = Tx(t) = x(t-\Delta)
$$

where $\Delta > 0$ is a constant. This is a model of a delay line. Is T bounded?

Using the definition of bounded operator, I should to prove that there exist a constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that, for all $x\ \in \text{ Domain}(T)$

$$
\|Tx\| \leq c\|x\|
$$

or suggest other method to solve this.

Comment: Yes, and $c = 1$. To prove this, use the definition of the norm $\|T\|$. There is no shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\|T x\| = \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}} |(Tx)(t)| = \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}} |x(t-\Delta)| = \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}} |x(t)| = \|x\|.$$